# Python and sockets +upnp

Tags: python

I have a question about python and sockets. As I understand, if you have router you must open a port before you can use it in your program. But if user can't do that...
I heard something about UPnP. I don't know will it help with my problem, so I've asked you.
Best regards.

Comment: Perhaps if you described your problem, you might get some help.  What you've posted here isn't very coherent.  And it doesn't look programming-related.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: For example, i want to create a server on my computer. And my friend tries to create a client. If i have a router, i must open a need port on my modem before i can use it. And if a have bridge, i mustn't do that.What can i do if i want to create server on all computers without port enabling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For UPnP support you can use [MiniUPnP](http://miniupnp.free.fr) library, it has python support.

Answer (score 0):

In usual setups, if you have a home router your machine doesn't have a public IP address, only the router has and does NAT for other machines to access the Internet.

In order to open a "listening" socket so internet machines can reach your private machine, you have to redirect a public port to your local machine.
For example public 1.2.3.4 port 2222 would be redirected to private 192.168.1.42 port 22 so you can ssh your machine from everywhere

Such redirections can be either configured manually on the router, or through protocols such as UPnP IGD, NAT-PMP and PCP

UPNP IGD is the most widespread one. See Miniupnp http://miniupnp.free.fr/ to the UPNP feature of your router. It has python bindings.